# How to save answers from a radio button type quiz to firebase databse even if some are unchecked

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code

> const ... = document.querySelector
>   ('input[name="..."]:checked').value;

And it only works when all radio buttons choices are checked. How to save answers even if some are unchecked?

I have tried getting rid of ":checked", but it just saves the first option for all, regardless even I chose different once. 
Then I have tried doing the following:

> const ... =document.querySelectorAll('input[name =" ... "]:not(:checked)')

But that didnt work out as well. Could someone please give me some advice on how to make that work?

html example of 1 question

> ```
>   <div id="question1"  style="position:fixed; left:20px; top: 50px;"> 
>       10
>
>           <label>  <input type="radio" name="q0" value="a1" id="a1" class="radio"> IMAGE 1 <br><br><br> </label>
>           <label>  <input type="radio" name="q0" value="a2" id="a2" class="radio"> IMAGE 2 <br><br><br> </label>
>           <label>  <input type="radio" name="q0" value="a3" id="a3" class="radio"> IMAGE 3 <br><br><br> </label>
>           <label>  <input type="radio" name="q0" value="a4" id="a4" class="radio"> IMAGE 4 <br><br><br> </label>
>           <label>  <input type="radio" name="q0" value="a5" id="a5" class="radio"> IMAGE 5 <br><br><br> </label>
>
>
>       </div>
> ```

JS

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);


var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('messages');


document.getElementById('contactForm').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);


function submitForm(e){   e.preventDefault();



  var a1 = getInputVal ('a1');   var a2 = getInputVal ('a2');   var a3
= getInputVal ('a3');   var a4 = getInputVal ('a4');   var a5 = getInputVal ('a5');





  saveMessage( a1, a2, a3,a4,a5);


  document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'block';


  setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'none';   },8000);


  document.getElementById('contactForm').reset(); }

function getInputVal(id){   return document.getElementById(id).value; }


function saveMessage( a1, a2, a3,a4,a5){   var newMessageRef = messagesRef.push();   newMessageRef.set({

    a1:a1,
    a2:a2,
    a3:a3,
    a4:a4,
    a5:a5,


  }); }

function saveMessage(){   const q1 = document.querySelector('input[name="q1"]:checked').value;
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Are you trying to get all the values from all checkboxes with a particular `name` into an array?

Comment: Please add some actual code. so I can understand. Add html snippet.

Comment: Basically I have a quiz with 10 questions. each question has its own "name" and 5 options to chose from. The problem is that if do not answer at least 1 question (meaning dont chose a radio button for 1 question) the submit button blocks and doesnt let me to submit the answer. As well, questions change each 30 seconds and it is impossible to answer previous questions if they are not answered.

Comment: @Mayur Added the js and html

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna get all the checkboxes doing querySelector, then check which one checked, which one aren't selected. I have added two functions with it, you can just run one for loop and do the same logic.

```js
function getUncheckedValues() {
  const obj = {};
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]'))
  .forEach((checkbox) => {
      obj[checkbox.value] = checkbox.checked
  });
  console.log(obj);
  return obj;
}

const resultEl = document.getElementById('checkedresult');
const resultUncheckEl = document.getElementById('uncheckedresult');

document.getElementById('showResult').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const values = getUncheckedValues();
  console.log(values);
  const newRef = firebase.database().ref('messages').push();
  newRef.set(values);
});
```

```html
<label>  <input type="radio" name="q0" value="a1" id="a1" class="radio"> IMAGE 1 <br><br><br> </label>
          <label>  <input type="radio" name="q0" value="a2" id="a2" class="radio"> IMAGE 2 <br><br><br> </label>
          <label>  <input type="radio" name="q0" value="a3" id="a3" class="radio"> IMAGE 3 <br><br><br> </label>
          <label>  <input type="radio" name="q0" value="a4" id="a4" class="radio"> IMAGE 4 <br><br><br> </label>
          <label>  <input type="radio" name="q0" value="a5" id="a5" class="radio"> IMAGE 5 <br><br><br> </label>


<br><br>
<button id="showResult">Show checked values</button>
<br><br>
<div id="checkedresult"></div>
<div id="uncheckedresult"></div>
```

Comment: @ Subhendu Kundu, Thank you very much! I have used what you have told me, but it only again saves the first answer, even if i chose the other one.. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @ Subhendu Kundu , It doesnt work unfortunately( . It gives me just the list of options for the question instead of the answer...(

Comment: That was just give to heads up, if you see the logic, you will see the true boo is giving you the answer. Now you need to modify the data format the way you want to.

Comment: `a1:a1,
    a2:a2,
    a3:a3,
    a4:a4,
    a5:a5,
` in this how are you finding which one is checked?

Comment: @ Subhendu Kundu I remember which one stands for which, and when In firebase database i see a3 i remember that it is the 3rd option. These options are being selected by a person

Comment: Dude, I meant `function saveMessage( a1, a2, a3,a4,a5){   var newMessageRef = messagesRef.push();   newMessageRef.set({

    a1:a1,
    a2:a2,
    a3:a3,
    a4:a4,
    a5:a5,


  }); }` when you do this, in firebase how will you identify which one was checked? cause this is just a1: someValue, a2: another value. There is no flag for checked or unchecked.

Comment: @ Subhendu Kundu That part of the code is actually useless. I deleted it now. Thanks for mentioning

Comment: Cool, `.set({});` use this and set however you want to store the data.

Comment: That's alright, how you wanna sure the data? Which format?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic snippet. Which helps you to clear your way. Just copy the code below.

```
<div id="question1"  style="position:fixed; left:20px; top: 50px;">           
    <label>  <input type="radio" name="q0" value="a1" id="a1" class="radio" onchange="checkAns()"> IMAGE 1 <br><br><br> </label>
    <label>  <input type="radio" name="q0" value="a2" id="a2" class="radio" onchange="checkAns()"> IMAGE 2 <br><br><br> </label>
    <label>  <input type="radio" name="q0" value="a3" id="a3" class="radio" onchange="checkAns()"> IMAGE 3 <br><br><br> </label>
    <label>  <input type="radio" name="q0" value="a4" id="a4" class="radio" onchange="checkAns()"> IMAGE 4 <br><br><br> </label>
    <label>  <input type="radio" name="q0" value="a5" id="a5" class="radio" onchange="checkAns()"> IMAGE 5 <br><br><br> </label>
    <button id="btn" disabled>Button</button> 
</div>

<script>
    var a1 = document.getElementById('a1');
    var a2 = document.getElementById('a2');
    var a3 = document.getElementById('a3');
    var a4 = document.getElementById('a4');
    var a5 = document.getElementById('a5');

    function checkAns(){
        console.log(a1.checked, a2, a3, a4, a5);
        if (a1.checked || a2.checked || a3.checked || a4.checked || a5.checked) {
            document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false; 
        }
    }
</script>
```

This might be help.